# input box is not taking float value

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

> Blockquote
>   In case of Height field its taking 3 integer value ,its correct but after that it must take 2 floating value,eg 555.34
>   even i am using step="0.01" and max="3",but on keypress its not taking any float value after 3 digit
>   Blockquote

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
 var inputQuantity = [];
    $(function() {
      $(".form-control").each(function(i) {
        inputQuantity[i]=this.defaultValue;
         $(this).data("idx",i); // save this field's index to access later
      });
      $(document).on("keypress",".form-control", function (e) {
        var $field = $(this),
            val=this.value+''+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode),pattern;
        if(this.step==0.00)
          pattern=/[^0-9]/
          else
          pattern=/[^0-9.]/
        if ( val>parseInt(this.max,10)||pattern.test(val)|| (val.match(/\./) && (val.match(/\./g).length>1 || val.replace(/\d+\./,'').length>2))) {
               e.preventDefault();
        }
      });      
    });
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.areas = [{id : 'choice2', total : 0}];

     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({
               'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0
          });
     };
     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
          }
     };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="newscript.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
               <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottom-line no-gap">
                              <h6>Open New Row {{$index + 1}} 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-right-gap  btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="addNewChoice()" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="plus_icon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                   </button>

                              </h6> 
                              <div class="row walls top-gap">

                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="length">Length :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2"  min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.00">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="height">Height :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="height"   ng-model="choice.b2"  min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.01">
                                   </div>
                                 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="removeChoice()" id="minus_icon">
                                   </button>
                              </div>

                         </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works fine here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/z24mAf6XAeXe714BqWbY?p=preview)

Comment: @SatejS its not working,its taking the n number of integer and character ,thats wrong it must take only 3 integer and 2 float value eg 123.33

Comment: Sorry, working on it.

Comment: Your issue lies here `if ( val>parseInt(this.max,10)||pattern.test(val)|| (val.match(/\./) && (val.match(/\./g).length>1 || val.replace(/\d+\./,'').length>2))) `

Comment: Your function is weird.You're accepting a number, but the val is a string?Why?

Comment: @SatejS ya something wrong hear only,but not able to find where is the mistake,do you have any idea??

Comment: @SatejS  ya input type is number so i used string for pattern matching,if not required you can remove this,not a issue

Comment: Check the posted answer

Answer (score 0):

So i've gone ahead and really simplified this code. I understand that you were concerned with the value adhering to the format that produces something like `123.33`.

I've used the `ng-pattern` in the input type to ensure that the input is matched with the required pattern.

**The Regex**

```
[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{2}
```

**The HTML**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2" ng-pattern="/[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{2}/"  min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.00">
```

**The length and height fields will only be valid, if your input meets the required regex.**

Here is a [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/z24mAf6XAeXe714BqWbY?p=preview)

Comment: sorry to say but again its taking n number of digit,which u posted in pulnker

Comment: Yes, it will take `n` number of digits, but the field will not be valid until it matches the required pattern.This is precisely the beauty of Angular, you can validate the input against a pattern.If it isn't valid, it won't assign the ng-model the value.

Comment: it fine for a developer view,but as a user view its not valid,because user unfortunately  doesn't know the beauty of angular